# Communicate with page followers through private message using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing an application which manages Facebook pages. I wanted to understand if there's any method where using API, we can communication with users who have commented on my page through private message.

Thanks in advance and reading the question.

Thanks,
Hardik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the conversations endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/conversations

Be aware that you can´t initiate the communication, you can only reply to a user message and you can only send 2 messages before the user responds: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/conversation/messages#publish